# Comparing a NodeList to an Array of element id's

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I created a NodeList for the childNodes of the unordered list below

```
<body>
 <ul id="win" >win
  <li id="aa0">text</li>
  <li id="aa1"></li>
  <li id="aa2"></li>
  <li id="aa3"></li>
  <li id="aa4"></li>
  <li id="aa5"></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

and I created an Array of element id's that I want to compare the NodeList to

```
 ['aa0','aa1,'aa7','aa8']
```

and I used the following javascript (below) to compare the NodeList to the Array. 
The objectives are to determine which elements in the array are already in the DOM or need to be added to the DOM... AND to determine which elements currently in the DOM need to be removed so that I can append the UL to contain only the id's that are in the array.

```
function  nodeinfo(){
 //these are the ids that we want in the ul
 var ids=['aa0','aa1','aa7','aa8']

 var node=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
 var nodelist=node.childNodes;

     //test to see if array ids are in nodelist
     for(var j=0;j<ids.length;j++){
        if(document.getElementById(ids[j])){alert(ids[j]+" is here, keep")}
        else{alert(ids[j]+" is not here, add")}
        }

     //test to see if nodelist ids are in array
     for(var j=0;j<nodelist.length;j++){
         if(nodelist[j].id != undefined){ 
            var tempi=0
            for(var k=0;k<ids.length;k++){
                if(nodelist[j].id === ids[k]){tempi++}
                }
            if (tempi !=1){alert(nodelist[j].id+" is unwanted, remove")}
            }
        }
    }
```

currently I'm just showing alerts where I will reference appending the structure. 
Please note that I'm pretty new at this. I'm aware that NodeLists do not behave like arrays and that adjusting the DOM in the middle of this function would change the NodeList and probably screw everything up.

My questions are these: This seems kind of bulky, is there a more concise or robust approach to this objective? and is there any inherent danger in trying to adjust the DOM structure based on an array as I am showing here?

and please no jquery.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? If you can avoid old IEs, then things like `Array.filter` will be helpful

Comment: at the very least IE8 and above...but would prefer IE6

Comment: Out of curiosity, why _no jquery_? (Especially if you're planning to support IE6-8.)

Comment: If you need to determine which items need to be in the DOM and which need to be removed from the DOM (replicating the array of id's exactly) you're probably better off just running through the ID Array and creating a new list every time. Same end result, less logic.

Comment: I'm in learning mode, so I'd prefer to use pure javascript instead of jquery.

Comment: insteresting...so you're saying maybe just overwrite the entire ul so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead having an array of id's it would be easier to use an associative array. This will make your second loop significantly less-cumbersome:

```
var ids = {
   aa0: true,
   aa1: true,
   aa7: true,
   aa8: true
};

var remove = [];
var add = [];

for(var id in ids) if(ids.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    if(document.getElementById(id) === null) {
       remove.push(id);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var node = nodeList[i];

    if(typeof node.id !== undefined && !ids[node.id]) {
        remove.push(node.id);
    }
}
```

The `if` in the second loop can be changed to use an `indexOf` the following if you were using an array of id's:

```
if(typeof node.id !== undefined && ids.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    remove.push(node.id)
}
```

Performance-wise the first one is better since lookup from an associative array is `O(1)` (unless you have a collision) whereas worst-case for `indexOf` is `O(n)` (meaning it has to go through the entire list to find out if the key exists in the worst case).

Comment: very nice. Thank you. Would creating a function to convert an array of id's into an associative array make sense on top of this?

Comment: still pretty green with objects, but I'm pushing my way through it.

Comment: @WilliamSmith Is that the only way you can get your id's? As an array? I will edit my solution to show you how to use arrays also.

Comment: currently I would be passing id arrays into the function as variables because I've been comfortable doing it that way, but I'm really looking for speed and efficiency, so using objects as associative arrays may be the best bet. If you could show the array option also that would be great.